# Could not find or load main class com.amazon.aes.webservices.client.cmd

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2

After I run the EC2 API tools, I run the command: ./ec2-cmd

However, I still get the error: Error: Could not find or load main class com.amazon.aes.webservices.client.cmd.

According to the guide: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonEC2/gsg/2006-06-26/running-an-instance.html

I'm suppose to run the ec2 commands, but none of the commands run due to the error above.

Any solutions?

Comment: Did you follow the [getting started guide?](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SettingUp_CommandLine.html) Sounds like you've just misconfigured one of the environment variables. In fact I'm nearly sure of it because otherwise you'd be using `ec2-cmd`, not `./ec2-cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

You must have the environment variable $JAVA_HOME and java correctly configured. The Path environment variable also needs to include the EC2_HOME directory.

```
export EC2_HOME=/usr/local/ec2/ec2-api-tools-xxxversion
export PATH=$PATH:$EC2_HOME/bin
```

You can refer to the instructions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/set-up-ec2-cli-linux.html as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it:

```
export CLASSPATH=$EC2_HOME/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite using the command line tools 1.7.1.0 installed via homebrew.

The problem was the ec2-cmd was setting the classpath to look for a lib/ folder within my $EC2_HOME.  That folder didn't exist.  I fixed it by adding a symlink to where all my jars were:

```
cd $EC2_HOME
ln -s libexec/lib lib
```

And then all of my commands started working.